# How to separately detect variables in URL using PHP?

Tags: php

consider my website's URL is `https://www.sitename.com/compare/product/product-name-s10-compare-102883.html?id=102903-102904-102905`
I want to detect the 102903 and 102904 and 102905 separately.
Using `$id1 = $_GET[ 'pid' ];` will give the `102903-102904-102905` as output. But I want `$id1`,`$id2`,`$id3` separately.
This function is to detect product ID from URL and show the comparison data in the page.

Comment: _"Using $id1 = $_GET[ 'pid' ]; will give the 102903-102904-102905"_ No it won't. Anyway, look into PHP's [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function

Comment: @j08691, Thank You explode function seems to be working fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [explode single variable in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26055215/explode-single-variable-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you look at `$_GET['id']` you get the entire string after the `=` sign, until the next variable. To split the string into three variables, use the [`split()`](https://www.php.net/split) function to create an array with separating by a string. The code for that would become something like this:

```
$id = split('-', $_GET['id']);
$id1 = $id[0];
$id2 = $id[1];
$id3 = $id[2];
```

Comment: Thank You, both the explode and split functions seems to be working fine.

Comment: Great, here on Stack Overflow you can mark an answer as solved, that way people will know what solved the problem and that they don't need to answer themselves. You can do this by clicking the checkmark left to the answer :)